# nested if in list/ dataframe with python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for which I have columns `df['kVA']` and `df['Phase']`. I am trying to create a column `df['Line']`, but with the following criteria:

1. Define line by phase

   ```
   df['Line']=['1PH' if x=='1PH' else '3PH' for  x in df['Phase'] ]
   ```
2. Define line by phase & kVa - desired output

   ```
   df['Line']=['1PH' if x=='1PH' else ['3PHSM' if y<=750 else '3PHLG' for y in df['kVA']] for  x in df['Phase'] ]
   ```

The code for define by phase works . But If I try to integrate the nested if the code stalls. I am trying to classify products to manufacturing lines by Phase and kVA characteristics. Both kVA and Phase are columns in my data frame (as attached).

How can I fix this?

[image: Data frame overview]

Comment: Can you please format your question to conform to the standards on SO?

Comment: use button `{}` to format code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is a great tool. I would do it this way:

```
# create some similar data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Phase': ['1PH', '3PH', '3PH', '1PH'], 'kVA': [50, 750, 300, 37.5]})

# add a new column (some elements will not change)
df['Line'] = df['Phase']
# modify rows that fit your criteria
df.loc[ (df.kVA < 750) & (df.Phase == '3PH'), 'Line'] += 'SM'
df.loc[ (df.kVA >= 750) & (df.Phase == '3PH'), 'Line'] += 'LG'
```

`.loc` and `iloc` are great for filtering part of your dataframe.

Note: I'm using Pandas v0.20.3 for this test.

Answer (score 0):

To do that in a more pandas like fashion you probably want to do something more like this:

```
one_phase = df['Phase'] == '1PH'
small = df['kVA'] <= 750

df['Line'][one_phase] = '1PH'
df['Line'][~one_phase & small] = '3PHSM'
df['Line'][~one_phase & ~small] = '3PHLG'
```

Note: You did not leave any parsable sample data so this was not tested.